# Do not understand what "#" key means with Haml in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I setup a starter package on my local machine.

As I looked through it I found this in one of the html.haml files:

```
%p
  Welcome #{@email}!
%p You can confirm your account email through the link below:
%p= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token)
```

I think that the `!` is part of the message to the user and I believe the `@email` is a variable with string text and is the person's email address.

However, I don't quite understand what the `#` does with the email. From the Haml documentation I believe that the `#` symbol makes a div as show from the example on [the Haml site](http://haml.info/tutorial.html), but this doesn't really make sense so if anyone could explain what it means I would greatly appreciate it.

Haml site example:

```
#content
  .left.column
    %h2 Welcome to our site!
    %p= print_information
  .right.column
    = render :partial => "sidebar"
```

Comment: `#{...}` syntax is for string interpolation. This will get evaluated by the interpreter and will replace what's inside the braces with the interpreted value. e.g. `@email = 'your_name@example.com` then `Welcome #{@email}! => Welcome your_name@example.com!`

Comment: @engineersmnky- add that comment as an answer so it can be accepted and found for future searchers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` is for setting the id of an element if it is [part of an element](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#class_and_id__and_), possibly an [implicit `div`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#implicit_div_elements).

In plain text (i.e. not in an element definition) [the `#{...}` syntax does interpolation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_). The contents are evaluated as Ruby, and the result is inserted into the output at this point. In this case, if `@email` had the value `matt@example.com` the result would be:

```
Welcome matt@example.com!
```

If you want to start a line with some interpolation you can escape the `#` with `\`, otherwise it would be interpreted as the start of an element and you would likely get an error.